PHP JWT token flow in Symfony
I am working on an app with separate front-end and backend. I need to create API routes which are protected by a JWT token.
On login/register the user gets back a JWT token(short lived) and refresh token(long lived). Refresh token is stored in HTTPOnly cookie.
The frontend attaches the JWT token to Authorization Header in format "Bearer jwt_token".
I am not sure how to handle the flow when the JWT expires.
If the refresh token exists in the cookie and in the database and has not been used before I generate a new JWT token.
How do I replace the old JWT token with the new one in the Authorization Header?
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Service\AuthApiService;
use AppBundle\Service\JWTAuthService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;

class ApiKeyListener
{
    private $em;
    /**
     * @var AuthApiService
     */
    private $authApiService;
    /**
     * @var JWTAuthService
     */
    private $JWTAuthService;

    private $apiKey;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, AuthApiService $authApiService, JWTAuthService $JWTAuthService, $apiKey)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->authApiService = $authApiService;
        $this->JWTAuthService = $JWTAuthService;
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'kernel.request' => ['onKernelRequest', 255], // 255 ensures this listener runs before others
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if ($request->headers->has('Authorization'))
        {
            $authorizationHeader = $request->headers->get('Authorization');
            if (strpos($authorizationHeader, 'Bearer ') === 0)
            {
                // A bearer token has been passed
                $this->validateJWT($request);
            }
        }

    }

    public function validateJWT(Request $request): void
    {
        $credentials = $request->headers->get('Authorization');
        $credentials = str_replace('Bearer ', '', $credentials);

        $isSignatureValid = $this->JWTAuthService->validateSignature($credentials);

        if (!$isSignatureValid['success']) throw new AuthenticationException($isSignatureValid['message']);

        $isActive = $this->JWTAuthService->isJWTTokenActive($credentials, $request->cookies->get('refresh_token'));

        if (!$isActive['success']) throw new AuthenticationException($isActive['error']['message']);

        setcookie('refresh_token', $isActive['data']['refresh_token'], time() + 3600 * 24 * 7, '/', null, false, true);

        $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $isActive['data']['token']);
        
        $user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->find($isActive['data']['user_id']);

        $request->attributes->set('user', $user->getId());
    }
}

$request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $isActive['data']['token']);

This doesn't change the header. I am guessing this is how it should be for security reasons.
The frontend is in React.
How should I implement this feature so it changes the JWT for new requests? Or is this done in the frontend and if so how?

This is a programming question for communities like Stack Overflow, not a security question. Sure, JWT is used in security contexts, but the problem you're facing has nothing to do with attackers, risks or protecting assets, it's purely an implementation issue related to PHP/Symfony/React.

How is the short lived Auth Token stored? Also as a HTTPOnly cookie? I am guessing not, since it is sent as a header, right?

Correct, short lived auth token is not stored as a HTTPOnly cookie. I thought this is a bad practice. So it is not stored anywhere only send in the header.

You mentioned, that the JWT refresh tokens are stored as HTTPOnly cookies. These cookies cannot be accessed by React or JavaScript in general, but are still sent with every request.
The important question is, how the access tokens are stored. Since they are passed as a header, it is unlikely they are stored as HTTPOnly cookies from my understanding. Here's an example on how the front end handles adding Authorization headers to an API request:
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = () => {
  const token = document.cookie
    .split(';')
    .find(row => row.startsWith('authToken='))
    ?.split('=')[1];
  return `Bearer ${token}`;
};

function fetchData() {
  axios.get('/api/protected-data')
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

In this example we read the cookie called authToken and append it to every request as Authorization: Bearer {ourCookie}. For this to function it is not allowed to be HTTPOnly.
If they are stored as normal cookies you either have the option to return the newly generated tokens as a JSON or add a Set-Cookie header in your response. However it is not possible to use $request->headers->set for this.
If you want to return the tokens as a JSON you can use the JsonResponse object:
// Assume we have a token object (e.g. from Doctrine)
return new JsonResponse([
     'token' => $newToken->getToken(),
     'refresh_token' => $newToken->getRefreshToken(),
     'expires_at' => $new_token->getExpiresAt()
]);

If you want to directly set the cookie using Symfony:
$access_cookie = Cookie::create(
     "access_token", 
     $cookieValue,
     $expireTime,
     '/', // Path (optional)
     null, // Domain (optional)
     false, // HttpOnly flag (Important to be false, since it needs to be read by React)
     true, // Secure flag (recommended for HTTPS)
     false // SameSite attribute (optional, refer to documentation)
);

$refresh_cookie = Cookie::create(
     "refresh_token", 
     $cookieValue,
     $expireTime,
     '/', // Path (optional)
     null, // Domain (optional)
     true, // HttpOnly flag (Important to be true, since it's supposed to be secured as good as possible)
     true, // Secure flag (recommended for HTTPS)
     false // SameSite attribute (optional, refer to documentation)
);

$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie($access_cookie);
$response->headers->setCookie($refresh_cookie);

return $response;

Cookie::create function
Let me know if this helped you or if you have any further questions

Hello, thanks for the answer. I thought of that solution as well but isn't storing JWT token in cookies a security risk?

@PVit Yes it is! From what you said it sounded like you're responsible for the backend only. Personally I use HTTPOnly Cookies for both access and refresh tokens. In this case you wouldn't be able to have the Authorization header, but would have to read the cookies from the requests. To be honest, I don't feel like I'm in the position to give you an definite answer to how you should store them, but that's how I do it and it has worked for me. If you find a better solution feel free to let me know as well!
